# Solving $\frac{2x^2}{x-1}\cdot 2^x+8=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions, transcendental-equations

So recently, a friend of mine in grade $12$ got this question on her homework.

$$\left(\frac{2x^2}{x-1}\right)\left(2^x\right)+8=0$$

I tried rearranging this expression into $$\frac{-4x+4}{x^2}=2^x$$

and taking natural log on both sides and see if I can isolate the x, and in the end, I got
$$\ln\left(-4x+4\right)+2\ln\left(x\right)=x\ln(2).$$

However, I am not sure what I can do next. Is there something I am missing, or is this not the way I should approach this question?

I also searched how to do equations with an exponential function and polynomial on the Math Stack Exchange before, but they say you will need to employ Lambert's W function; I am not sure how you would rearrange this equation to use it.

Comment: This equation might not have a nice analytical solution. The numerical solution is close to 0.757

Comment: thanks, I was also thinking that might be the case

Comment: Could you check the original problem? It seems there is no analytical solution for this problem, and here is the plot from desmos. The numerical root searching from Mathematica is $x=0.757493...$
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eya8rqitor

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Some more context would be helpful here. If your friend's homework is a textbook exercise, what relevant topics, tools, and/or techniques were covered in the chapter? (For that matter, what course is your friend taking?) If this is a contest practice problem or online challenge, then what is the target audience expected to know? This information can help people avoid explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond the intended level of the problem.

Comment: Even Lamberts W function is a numerical solution, so most of this kind of equations are solved numerically. Why not us a numerical method like Newton?

Comment: Did the directions say "solve" or something else.  Like "what's the domain?" or "graph".

Comment: the direction says to solve

Comment: @IV_ This is for high school, I am sorry if I wasn't being clear.

Comment: It might (?) be easier to use numerical methods (at HS level) on the following rearrangement: $$x^2=(1-x)2^{2-x}$$ (This doesn't isolate $x$ but it's a bit simpler.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is for symbolic solutions ([closed-form solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)). It's probably beyond high school level. In high school, they instead learn solving equations also numerically.
$\ $

$$\frac{2x^2}{x-1}2^x+8=0$$

$$\frac{2x^2}{x-1}e^{\ln(2)x}+8=0$$

Because your equation contains two algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^{\ln(2)x}$), there is possibly no non-constant [(partial) inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) that is an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).
But if the equation can have solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) is a different mathematical problem.

For applying Lambert W, we want to try to rearrange your equation to the form

$$F(f(x)e^{f(x)})=F(y),$$

where $F$ and $f$ are unary functions in the complex numbers, and $y$ is independent of $x$.

$$\frac{2x^2}{x-1}2^x+8=0$$

$$\frac{-4x+4}{x^2}=2^x$$

$$\frac{-4x+4}{x^2}=e^{\ln(2)x}$$

$$\frac{x^2}{-4x+4}e^{\ln(2)x}=1$$

We see, the general equation isn't in a form that allows to apply Lambert W.

But it can be solved by Generalized Lambert W:

$$x=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}W\left(^{0,\ \ 0}_{\ln(2)};-4\ln(2)\right)=-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}W\left(^{-\ln(2)}_{0,\ \ 0};-\frac{1}{4\ln(2)}\right)$$

$-$ see the references below.
$\ $

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Comment: wow, thanks so much; I will read those papers definitely

Comment: @KevinZhang That aren't standard solutions. It seems to be a special new topic of research. See the other questions answered by  generalized Lambert W in MathStackExchange and mathOverflow.

Comment: ok I will check them out

Answer (score 0):

Beside the generalized Lambert function, only numerical methods would solve the problem.

However, we can make decent approximation since, graphing, you notced that the solution is close to $\frac 34$.

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\frac{2^{x+1} x^2}{1-x}-8$$ which is far from linearity. So, instead, consider $$g(x)=\log \left(\frac{2^{x+1} x^2}{1-x}\right)-\log(8)$$ Using Taylor series
$$\log \left(\frac{2^{x+1} x^2}{1-x}\right)=\log \left(\frac{9}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\right)+\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)
   \left(\frac{20}{3}+\log (2)\right)+\frac{56}{9}
   \left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+\frac{1856}{81}
   \left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^3+O\left(\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^4\right)$$
Now, using series reversion
$$x=\frac{3}{4}+t-\frac{56 }{3 (20+\log (8))}t^2-\frac{ (73216+22272 \log
   (2))}{108 (20+\log (8))^2}t^3+O\left(t^4\right)$$ where $$t=\frac{3 \left(g(x)+\log(8)+\log \left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{2}}{9}\right)\right)}{20+\log (8)}\tag 1$$

Since we want $g(x)=0$, $t=\frac{3 \log \left(\frac{8192}{6561}\right)}{4 (20+\log (8))}$. Plugged in $(1)$, you have a (nasty) explicit expression for the estimate; converted to decimals, this gives
$x=\color{red}{0.7574926}57$ while the solution given by Newton method is
$x=\color{red}{0.757492663}$.